# HMM with final or absorbing state

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I am reading about HMMs and it's unclear to me if they are required to have a final state. In particular I have seen examples of HMMs that have an absorbing state and other examples with no final state.

Can you please explain, if it necessary to model a final state explicitly or is something that applies in certain HMM models(e.g. speech recognition)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no particular necessity for a *final* state.  The underlying structure is of a random walk on a directed graph.  Any notions that apply in that context such as *transience* or *recurrence*, apply here, but are not necessary in HMM, in general.  Any specific use of them is specific to the problem.